# c# HttpRequestMessage Authorization returns 401 with IdentityServer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have an IdentityServer4 server that I'm running for demo purposes (I have followed the getting started guide in the IdentityServer4 documentations). I am able to get a token from it, and I am able to use this token to get information from a protected resource when using Postman.

But when I try to use this token from my c# code, I'm getting a 401 response (same token in Postman works fine). The way I set up the request in my code is as follow:

```
httpRequestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "{token string}");
```

I know that the server accepts the token. I have added a console to write the token in different requests coming to the server and compared it to what I get with Postman. This is my output:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:5000/connect/token application/x-www-form-urlencoded 87
>>>>>>>>>>>>> PATH: /connect/token
>>>>>>>>>>>>> AUTH:
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Request path /connect/token matched to endpoint type Token
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Endpoint enabled: Token, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint for /connect/token
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint[0]
      Start token request.
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.ClientSecretValidator[0]
      Start client validation
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.BasicAuthenticationSecretParser[0]
      Start parsing Basic Authentication secret
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.PostBodySecretParser[0]
      Start parsing for secret in post body
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.SecretParser[0]
      Parser found secret: PostBodySecretParser
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.SecretParser[0]
      Secret id found: client
dbug: IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore[0]
      client configuration validation for client client succeeded.
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.SecretValidator[0]
      Secret validator success: HashedSharedSecretValidator
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.ClientSecretValidator[0]
      Client validation success
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator[0]
      Start token request validation
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator[0]
      Start client credentials token request validation
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator[0]
      client credentials token request validation success
info: IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator[0]
      Token request validation success, {
        "ClientId": "client",
        "GrantType": "client_credentials",
        "Scopes": "api1",
        "Raw": {
          "grant_type": "client_credentials",
          "client_id": "client",
          "client_secret": "***REDACTED***",
          "username": "",
          "password": "***REDACTED***"
        }
      }
dbug: IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService[0]
      Getting claims for access token for client: client
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint[0]
      Token request success.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 343.2786ms 200 application/json; charset=UTF-8
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/values/ application/json; charset=utf-8 4
>>>>>>>>>>>>> PATH: /api/values/
>>>>>>>>>>>>> AUTH: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjYyNGM5MmFkZGZmNGMzN2I1ZDFmMTdmZjI2ZGQ4MmQ0IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJuYmYiOjE1Njc5MzMwMTcsImV4cCI6MTU2NzkzNjYxNywiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MDAwIiwiYXVkIjpbImh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTAwMC9yZXNvdXJjZXMiLCJhcGkxIl0sImNsaWVudF9pZCI6ImNsaWVudCIsInNjb3BlIjpbImFwaTEiXX0.wILiCZ_H8-8ZyIYjxwt_Z7Mixr6wk1bwF0n2MTLrSkT7lZUShM1LFrmRaMAj37vJMN86a4q-WmBfqWhsxmfn8IqYn7GwlWOFIzbeHgaiqL0I4FsBPNzXNmBt_jkmMVwfLrxFWQ7b-6rucXvcNJjr9hUKQ-3jhF3nw7Za9D-YclnBH8NOOg5V1z7lTQOAU-5B7YbZut9uh1RYnOO2Spqg-EQ8Qd00Yy4sdNLidH1yZi6MoTgNhqmx4mV64oQERrdAzMPdw2-DlWYk8Ujd-qixNwCHHAlA35XlQZFHnZSrOrJwTNJBF-xGypbBQvLtqbWxD3ZnvuZcQ-ItGiIF9CFX-g
info>>>>>>>>>>>>> PATH: /.well-known/openid-configuration
>>>>>>>>>>>>> AUTH:
: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Request path /.well-known/openid-configuration matched to endpoint type Discovery
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Endpoint enabled: Discovery, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint[0]
      Start discovery request
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 44.5515ms 200 application/json; charset=UTF-8
>>>>>>>>>>>>> PATH: /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks
>>>>>>>>>>>>> AUTH:
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Request path /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks matched to endpoint type Discovery
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Endpoint enabled: Discovery, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint[0]
      Start key discovery request
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 26.8755ms 200 application/jwk-set+json; charset=UTF-8
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[2]
      Successfully validated the token.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 242.3834ms 307
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[32]
      Connection id "0HLPK7A0C1DTP", Request id "0HLPK7A0C1DTP:00000001": the application completed without reading the entire request body.
info>>>>>>>>>>>>> PATH: /api/values/
>>>>>>>>>>>>> AUTH:
: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/api/values/ application/json; charset=utf-8 4
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'AuthServerDemo.Controllers.ValuesController.Get (AuthServerDemo)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Route matched with {action = "Get", controller = "Values"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]] Get() on controller AuthServerDemo.Controllers.ValuesController (AuthServerDemo).
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
      Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action AuthServerDemo.Controllers.ValuesController.Get (AuthServerDemo) in 27.7154ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint 'AuthServerDemo.Controllers.ValuesController.Get (AuthServerDemo)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 88.7948ms 401
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[32]
      Connection id "0HLPK7A0C1DTR", Request id "0HLPK7A0C1DTR:00000001": the application completed without reading the entire request body.
```

When calling `api/values` endpoint I see that the request is accepted with the token. Then it makes a call to `.well-known/openid-configuration`, then a call to `.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks` and then another call to `api/values` but this time with an empty authorization token.

If I compare this to the Postman call, then on the second call to the `api/values` endpoint it does have the authorization token.

What am I missing on my request setup? And can someone explain the extra calls made on the server side and why the call to `api/values` is done twice?

Comment: What configuration have you used in startup.cs file for Authorization Setup?

Comment: Could you explain your settings? Where is your API hosted, together with identityserver or separately? I see a mess of logs: some from IdSrv, some from JwtBearer middleware. And two requests: one to http://localhost:5000/api/values and the other to https://localhost:5001/api/values. In general an API must behave the following way: call `.well-known/openid-configuration` to get `jwks` endpoint, call `.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks` to get the keyset, validate the token with the keyset

Comment: When you host your API together with Identityserver (not recommended for general purposes), you can get rid of additional http traffic by using `services.AddAuthentication().AddLocalApi("token", isAuth => { });` instead of `.AddIdentityServerAuthentication()`

Comment: @d_f Thanks for the reply. I don't host them together. This is for demonstration purposes only.

Comment: but still... are you facing the problem with that your "demo environment"? according to your logs it looks like you initially call it over http and then your `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` takes place and switches the traffic to https:// and 5001. probably Posman handles that and reattaches the token to the second request... or it's configured to connect over https from the beginning

Comment: Found the problem. It was due to redirection that the `HttpClient` does out-of-the-box but does not reattach headers to. Fixed it. It has nothing to do with the auth environment itself. I will write an answer about it here in case someone needs the solution in the future.

Comment: That was more or less clear from the beginning out of the logs. That was what I tried to ask you to check. Postman is not a good tool to compare with. It makes some strange things behind the scene without any warning nor excuse. And finally it's buggy. My suggestion is to try curl its output is much more trasible and reliable.

Answer (score -1):

You need to configure IdentityServer EndPoint in API project as below

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddMvcCore()
    .AddAuthorization()
    .AddJsonFormatters();

    services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";//IdentityServer4 Endpoint
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

        options.ApiName = "api1";//Name of resource
    });

}
```

Comment: I have. It's configured. As mentioned in my post i'm able to call everything properly using Postman - only when calling from code it makes the described problems.